Flutter app development: epub_view, dart:io, and universal_io incompatibility. How to resolve?
I'm trying to build a cross-platform e-reader app in Flutter. To ensure compatibility with web, I have been usinguniversal_io. BUT the epub_view package apparently does not support universal_io, and only dart:io exclusively... and for a e-reader app, epub support is essential.
To handle this, I tried to conditionally use dart:io.File for non-web platforms while excluding it on web.
The error I can't get rid of:
flutter run -d chrome
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib/src/features/book_reader/components/epub_viewer.dart:58:41: Error: The argument type 'File/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File/*2*/'.
 - 'File/*1*/' is from 'dart:io'.
 - 'File/*2*/' is from 'package:universal_file/src/io/file.dart' ('/C:/Users/Larry/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/universal_file-1.0.0/lib/src/io/file.dart').
        document: EpubDocument.openFile(file),
                                        ^

Here’s the latest version of my code, including my attempts to solve this issue:

Using conditional imports with if (dart.library.html) to selectively import dart:io or universal_io.
Adding explicit aliases (dart_io.File and universal_io.File) to avoid type ambiguity.
Ensuring no dart:io code runs on web by guarding with kIsWeb.

// src/features/book_reader/components/epub_viewer.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'package:epub_view/epub_view.dart';

// Explicitly import dart:io with an alias
import 'dart:io' as dart_io;

// Explicitly import universal_io with an alias
import 'package:universal_io/io.dart' as universal_io;

class EpubViewerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String filePath;
  final String? title;
  final Function(double)? onProgressChanged;
  final double initialProgress;

  const EpubViewerScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.filePath,
    this.title,
    this.onProgressChanged,
    this.initialProgress = 0.0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EpubViewerScreen> createState() => _EpubViewerScreenState();
}

class _EpubViewerScreenState extends State<EpubViewerScreen> {
  late EpubController _epubController;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  String? _errorMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadBook();
  }

  Future<void> _loadBook() async {
    try {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        // EPUB not supported on the web
        throw UnsupportedError('EPUB viewing is not supported on the web.');
      }

      // Use dart:io.File for non-web platforms
      final dart_io.File file = dart_io.File(widget.filePath);

      // Ensure the file exists
      if (!await file.exists()) {
        throw dart_io.FileSystemException('File not found', widget.filePath);
      }

      // Initialize the EpubController with the dart:io.File
      _epubController = EpubController(
        document: EpubDocument.openFile(file),
      );

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        _errorMessage = null;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _errorMessage = 'Error loading EPUB: ${e.toString()}';
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title ?? 'EPUB Reader')),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('EPUB viewing is not supported on the web platform.'),
        ),
      );
    }

    if (_isLoading) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title ?? 'EPUB Reader')),
        body: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    }

    if (_errorMessage != null) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title ?? 'EPUB Reader')),
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Icon(Icons.error_outline, color: Colors.red, size: 48),
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text(
                  _errorMessage!,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 24),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _loadBook,
                  child: const Text('Retry'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title ?? 'EPUB Reader'),
      ),
      body: EpubView(
        controller: _epubController,
        onChapterChanged: (chapter) {
          if (widget.onProgressChanged != null && chapter != null) {
            widget.onProgressChanged!(0.5);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _epubController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

So,

Is there a way to completely isolate the dart:io.File type so it doesn’t conflict with universal_io.File?
Are there better ways to approach cross-platform compatibility for file handling in this situation? For example, are there any cross-platform alternatives to epub_view which would be compatible with universal_io?

I’d greatly appreciate any guidance. I’ve been stuck on this issue for days and am starting to feel like I’m going in circles.
Thank you in advance for your help!
